# Python How to get integers from the list?

Tags: python, list, integer

I have a list with integers with white space in between. I'd like to retrieve all those individual integer and make a new list with an index.

```
>>> x = ['1 2 3 4']
>>> type(x)
<class 'list'>
>>> len(x)
1
```

I want to convert the list into

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> type(x)
<class 'list'>
>>> len(x)
4
```

I'm trying with split, it didn't work. How do I do the conversion?

Comment: xl = [int(n) for n in x[0].split()]

Comment: Thank you all! . That was amazing!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one straightforward way to do it:

```
>>> map(int, x[0].split())
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here:

- `x[0]` converts `['1 2 3 4']` into `'1 2 3 4'`;
- `.split()` converts it into `['1', '2', '3', '4']`;
- `map(int, ...)` converts it into `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

That said, it's not totally clear why you have a list in the first place, given that it appears to only have one element (a string of space-separated numbers).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
x = ['1 2 3 4']
final_x = [int(i) for i in x[0] if i.isdigit()]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use lambda and map something like this:

```
a = ['1 2 3 4']


print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:int(y),x.split())),a)))
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```